# Stacking 3 layers of a sheet cake

Tags: cake

Can I stack 3 layers of a half sheet cake on top of each other without having boards inbetween and just using dowels through the 3 layers?

Comment: It…. depends? Fay, can you add a bit more info about what kind of cake and what you plan to add between the layers?